# how to pass array index to ngfor in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects in the following structure

```
datas = data: [
    [{id:1}]
    [{id:2}]
...
]
```

in angular 4 template

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
{{ data.id }}
</div>
```

but this dont work,
What could I do?

Comment: Change it to  `{{ data[0].id }}`, it will work, but this stinks (seems like something is very wrong).

Comment: This dont work for me. But it is resolved, i'm ask to api developer for pass only array. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an array inside your array... Here is a way to fix.

**TS**

```
datas = data: [
    {id:1}
    {id:2}
...]
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
{{ data.id }}
</div>
```